# How to extract files to another directory using 'tar' command?

Tags: tar

I thought `tar archive.tar /users/mylocation` would work, but it doesn't. How can I do that?

Comment: Also, `-C, --directory DIR\n change to directory DIR` should rather be described as `change output directory to DIR (will fail if DIR doesn't exist)`. Thanks @Mich. See also @Bryan_Larsen's answer.

Comment: @Ujjwal Sing : Indeed, the tar man page is not that helpful. It describes "-C DIR" as "change to directory DIR" .  Even worse: "tar -C mydir xf archive.tar " doesn't work, while "tar xf archive.tar -C mydir" does.

Comment: @PatMorin To be fair, once you understand the argument calling conventions you're using it makes sense. You can also do `tar xfC archive.tar mydir` or `tar -C mydir -xf archive.tar`. It's only mixing traditional-style and GNU-style flags that breaks things, as... is honestly kind of expected. Traditional flags are passed all as one blob as the first argument. You can't expect them to work if they're not the first. (I mean, yes, it's possible to interpret it anyway -- my point is that'd be above and beyond, not standard)

Answer (score 1300, accepted):

To extract an archive to a directory different from the current, use the `-C`, or `--directory`, tar option, as in

```
tar -xf archive.tar -C /target/directory
```

Note that the target directory has to exist before running that command (it can be created by `mkdir /target/directory`).

Read the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/tar.1) (command: `man tar`) for other options.

Comment: If it's a larger file, when you run the command, all you get is no output for several seconds or even minutes while it's working. You can fix this by adding the `-v` flag (_verbose mode_) which lists the name of each file as it extracts it.

Comment: If you're having troubles with this, note the `--strip-components=1` advice from the other answer as well.

Comment: @consultstan https://xkcd.com/1168/

Comment: If output directory is long, in general, save to a variable like `$TargetDir` then `mkdir -p "$TargetDir" && tar --directory "$TargetDir" myfile.tar.gz`

Comment: Isn't it amazing that, after all these years, with all the options `tar` has accumulated, there still isn't an option to *create the output directory if it doesn't exist*?

Comment: I know it seems frustrating but linux's philosophy is "do one thing and do it well". That's because even for trivial things like creating a directory, it creates a lot more complexity when writing and maintaining a utility like `tar`. There are other tools that exist to create directories and tar's main function is to extract and compress files, which it does exceedingly well :)

Comment: I totally agree, there should be an option to *create* the output directory if it doesn't exist. Otherwise, you can just extract the file and use `mv`.

Comment: @MariusHofert mv is not convenient if the tar creates many files in current directory after extraction, if current directory already contains several files, it is difficult to know which ones came out of the tar file

Comment: A flag for "always expand in a folder of the name of the archive, except if the archive already outputs in a folder of the name of the archive"

Answer (score 354):

Note that if your tarball already contains a directory name you want to change, add the `--strip-components=1` option:

```
tar xf archive.tar -C /target/directory --strip-components=1
```

Comment: Thank you. Downloads via wget/etc always have a 'parent' directory. This is the complete answer imo - or should be noted in answer above.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. `--strip-components` is so useful when running provisioners that might use different versions. This way `/target/directory` can be a generic name, without having to worry about how the provider chose to name their archive folder.

Comment: Just a heads up, this can remove any number of leading directories, not just one: *--strip-components=NUMBER
       strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction*

Answer (score 45):

Combining the previous answers and comments:

To simply extract the contents and create target directory if it is missing:

```
mkdir -p /target/directory && tar xf archive.tar -C /target/directory
```

To extract and also remove the root(first level) directory in the zip

```
mkdir -p /target/directory && tar xf archive.tar -C /target/directory --strip-components=1
```

Comment: You can skip creating the directory by adding the `--one-top-level=/target/directory` option to the tar command, and removing the `-C` option. See this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470421/44793)

Answer (score 39):

Another option is to use --one-top-level. This will automatically create a directory based on the filename of the original.

```
tar zxvf filename.tgz --one-top-level
```

Additionally if you want, you can specify your own and tar will create it automatically.

```
tar zxvf filename.tgz --one-top-level=new_directory
```

Comment: I'm using GNU tar 1.26 and I get an unrecognized option error for `--one-top-level`

Comment: This is the answer I needed. Very useful "not" to have to specify the directory name, or remember special code that will refer back to the file for the name. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone on macOS, you'll need to install `gnu-tar` with `brew install gnu-tar` and then use `gtar` to get this command line option.

Answer (score 4):

What I found interesting in relation to extraction is, that it depends how you created the archive, see this example

```
cd /tmp
mkdir folder
touch folder/file.txt
```

when you do `tar -zcvf folder.tar.gz folder` everything is as expected = when you untar it now it will be untarred (folder will be create, if you removed it) as `/tmp/folder/`.

But, when you will create tar as `tar -zcvf tmp-folder.tar.gz /tmp/folder` and you untar it in `/tmp` folder, the result will be `/tmp/tmp/folder` directory ! In such case you have to untar it to `/` - `tar -xf tmp-folder.tar.gz -C /`