# How to make tar extract to new directory with option to create directory if not present?

Tags: command-line, bash, tar, zip, mkdir

The `tar` command has option to extra a file (`file_name.tgz`) into given directory (`directory_name`). ie.,

```
tar -zxf file_name.tgz -C directory_name
```

But it fails, if I try to run the above command, without creating directory (`directory_name`) prior to running this. Following is the error I got:

```
tar: directory_name: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Is there any option present in tar command to create this directory if not present?

The present work around I have, is by running `mkdir -p directory_name` in prior.

Comment: [How to extract files to another directory using 'tar' command](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018374/986805)

Comment: you can also use `mkdir -p directory && tar -xf filename.tgz -C $_`, $_ will contain the last argument of the previous command.

Comment: @bac0n what about the case when `mkdir` fails? It would be very rare, but still.

Comment: command && <-- and command, meaning if the first command fails the second command will not execute.

Comment: MithunB, `mkdir -p` will create the parent path too, so it will not fail, while the user has enough write permissions. @bac0n, please convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: @bac0n you are right about `&&`. I just overlook without paying much heed.