# How to extract the contents of a tar file into an existing directory

Tags: command-line, tar

Please do not mistake this question with "how to untar a tar file into an existing directory". For this question there are already answers such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/45354/1047017)

What I am trying to do is to untar an tar.gz file but put the **contents** into a directory

The linked answer for example when you do it creates a folder (with the name of the tar file) and puts the contents inside the folder

What I want is to *not create the folder* but put the contents inside an already existing directory.

How can this be done?

Comment: "What I am trying to do is to untar an tar.gz file but put the contents into a directory" - This is exactly what `tar -xf archive.tar -C /path/to/dir` is doing. There won't be any directories created with the name of the tar file.

Comment: Thanks but actually no. I found that I have to use `--strip-components 1` to do what I intend.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: That's the second answer in the linked post: https://askubuntu.com/a/470266/158442

Comment: @KansaiRobot This is not true. `--strip-components` will remove the first direrectory INSIDE the `tar` file. So it is content of your `tar` file! `tar -x` won't create any other directories. Note: `--strip-components` means, that if you have the same file name in different directories, they might get overwritten.